# Using Multiple Clocks in Testers

Tags: chisel

I have a module with multiple clocks, using `withClockAndReset`. When writing the testbench, how do I provide a clock stimulus on the named clock port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chisel-testers has very limited abilities for doing what you want. I think your best bet within the standard chisel stack is to try and use the new [chisel-testers2](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2). There is an example in the unit tests in that repo: [ClockDividerTest.scala](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2/blob/master/src/test/scala/chisel3/tests/ClockDividerTest.scala) and a couple of other clock related tests. This is a very active area of chisel development right now. If you can try this, the team is very interested in making this work.

Comment: I followed the spirit of that example - see post below with reasonably-formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following the spirit of that example, but didn't need chisel-testers2.

```
class MyModuleTestFixture(<params> extends Module {

  val dut = Module(new MyModule(<params>))

  val divClock = RegInit(true.B)
  divClock := ~divClock

  dut.io.explicit_clk := divClock.asClock()
  dut.io.all_other_ios <> io.all_other_ios
}
```

It's a restrictive way of generating the explicit clock, but served my purpose.